# How can I add a column from one dataframe to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one 18x30 (called df1) and one 2x30 (called df2), both of them have exactly the same index values.

I want to be able to add one of the columns from df2 to the end of df1.

The data types in df1 are all integer and the data type for df2 is string. Whenever I merge/concat/join, I get NaN instead of the right data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks :D

Comment: what is happening if you just do df1['newcol']=df2['col'] ?

Comment: Nevermind, solved it. Just needed to change the datatype

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The data types in df1 are all integer and the data type for df2 is
>   string. Whenever I merge/concat/join, I get NaN instead of the right
>   data.

If you want to add the df2 value to the df1 value, you need to convert the df2 field to an integer.

```
df2['FieldName'] = df2['FieldName'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 19):

if you want to add the column at the end, you can use

```
df1['columename']= df2['existing_colume_name']
```

and after that apply

```
df1.column_name = df1.column_name.astype(float)
```

This worked for me !

Answer (score 17):

correct answer:

```
df1['column_name'] = df2['column_name'].values
```

the thing is you need to pass an object of a certain type for it to work correctly. *List* or *array* are preferable.